# How do I get my button to work where it is clicked any place?

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the moment my hamburger button works just fine before it transforms, however after the hamburger button tranforms to the red "X" button if you click on any part of the "X" the button will transform, but it will not close the menu like it should. I can not find where I messed up.

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ex3z5o8L/

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: "Verdana";
    }
    #image {
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1 ;       
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content {
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#4d5555;
    }
    #footer {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }
    div#header #fullScreenNav{
        position:fixed;
        height:0px;
        width:100%;
        background:#000;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
        z-index:2;
    }
    #fullScreenNavbtn{
        background: #f3f3f3;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1  ;   
        top: 70vh;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
/* ---------------------------------------------------------Start Of Hamburger Button------------------------------------------------------- */
.c-hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.1s;
  border-radius:10px;    
  background: transparent;
  right:5px;
  top:5px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c-hamburger:hover span,
.c-hamburger:hover span::before,
.c-hamburger:hover span::after
{background: black;}

.c-hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius:100px;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  content: "";
  border-radius:100px;    
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -15px;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -15px;
}

.c-hamburger--htx {
}

.c-hamburger--htx span {
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-duration: 0.1s, 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s, 0s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before {
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active {
  background-color: #cb0032;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: white;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: white;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------------End of Hamburger Button-------------------------------------------------- */
</style>

</head>

<body>


<div id="header">
    <div id="headerBtnHolder">
    <img onload="parallex1('image')" src="" id="image" />
        <button id="fullScreenNavbt" class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx" onclick="toggleNavPanel('fullScreenNav','100vh','fullScreenNavbt')">
            <span>toggle menu</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="fullScreenNav">
        <div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>

<script>
(function() {

  "use strict";

  var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

  for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var toggle = toggles[i];
    toggleHandler(toggle);
  };

  function toggleHandler(toggle) {
    toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
    });
  }

})();
</script>
<script>
function toggleNavPanel(dropDivId, height, btnId){
    var panel = document.getElementById(dropDivId), maxH= height, nav = btnId;
  if(panel.style.height == maxH){
      panel.style.height = "0px";
    } else {
        panel.style.height = maxH;
    }
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
        if(event.target != panel && event.target.parentNode !=panel && event.target.id != nav ){
             panel.style.height = "0px"; 
        }
});
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parallex1(ObjectId){
    var ypos, image;
    function parallex () {
        ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        image = document.getElementById(ObjectId);
        image.style.top = ypos * .6 + 'px';
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', parallex);}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your fiddle works. Shows a gray box and when pressing the menu button shows a black box. If you press the X button the black box disappears.

Comment: Posted code should be a **minimal** example that displays the issue, 230 lines is excessive.

Comment: You have to press exactly on the white part of the X, and when you do it messes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic problem is that on every click you're adding an eventListener so you re creating an event hell. Remove the onClick and add the event listeners only once to run your methods. Also your checks for toggling the panel are wrong. There's a span inside the button which should toggle as well.

Comment: I'm still confused. If I take the onclick event off how is the button supposed to open the fullscreen panel?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rainb0w/ex3z5o8L/2/
Let me know if that works and if you need me to explain anything.. Btw I tried to change only the essential parts in your code but it would be better if instead of setting the height to toggle a class 'is-open' that would have the height. Also there's no benefit of adding separate script inline tags.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all of your effort!